# Sass Error (unmached bracket)

Tags: html, css, sass

What is the best way to find an unmatched bracket in any Mac editor (Sublime Text 3, Atom, Brackets etc. )

I am going nuts over this and have tried many things.

here is there error (grunt):

```
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
File "app/assets/css/style.unprefixed.css" created.

Running "cssmin:dev" (cssmin) task
File app/assets/css/style.min.css created.

Running "autoprefixer:dev" (autoprefixer) task
Warning: Can't parse CSS: @keyframes missing '}' near line 542:3 Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

I have combed the file from top to bottom and have found nothing.

this is the file:

https://github.com/SmithDesign-Info/MightyMC-You-Plus/blob/master/src/scss/partials/_main.scss

THIS IS NOT OFF TOPIC it is a relevant Web Dev question that deserves an answer.

I have tried:

"Try deleting sections of code until the error either goes away or changes."

"for all of those editors, there are short cuts to skip to matching brackets and minimize code between brackets. using both of those features you should find the issue in no time."  I have tried many plugins

Comment: There don't appear to be any keyframes in the file you linked. Have I missed something?

Comment: When I run that file through `sass` (after dealing with the missing values for "$orange" and "$blue", and commenting out the imports of "mcbutton") it works fine. What does the button thing look like?

Comment: https://github.com/SmithDesign-Info/MightyMC-You-Plus/blob/master/src/scss/modules/_buttons.scss

Comment: Where are the animations defined? That looks to be the source of the error.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening after the CSS minification steps, which likely means that the source files are not the problem (since SASS itself and the minifier had no problems). The missing brace is error has to do with what the minifier output  looks like. What happens if you do the autoprefixing first, before the minifier?

Comment: Changing the order does nothing

Comment: Paulie_D  the keyframe is on line 365. It is no the problem.  Removing it does not solve the problem

Comment: .main{
  /* No JS Fallback */
  .no-js .simform {
    font-size: 1.75em;
  } 

I think you've forgot to close this one.

Comment: Your previous question was not well received, so you thought it would be a good idea to delete it and repost it hoping for a different outcome?  Insisting that this question is on topic doesn't make it on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make my reply even clearer, I think that's the problem as its nested and forgot to close the first tag.

line: 542 in your git.

```
.main{
  /* No JS Fallback */
  .no-js .simform {
    font-size: 1.75em;
  }
```

to

```
.main{
  /* No JS Fallback */
      .no-js .simform {
        font-size: 1.75em;
      }
    }
```